# How do I load the indicators plugin?

Tags: meteor, npm, scrollmagic

I have included the `scrollmagic` NPM package, and from the ScrollMagic docs I get that;

> "To have access to this extension, please include
>   plugins/debug.addIndicators.js."

How do I load the indicators into my project?

Here is my code:

```
import ScrollMagic from 'scrollmagic'

var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller()
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({/*ScrollMagic code inside here*/})
    .addIndicators({name: "Animation trigger"})
    .addTo(controller)
```

Comment: Look into this path `scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins`. You will find `debug.addIndicators.js`. You need to import this file.

Comment: Not working. I tried to import debug.addIndicators.js alone, alonside with scrollmagic, different orders... nothing happers. addIndicators() doesn't show anything. When I import both of them, the are errors because names overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Please add this part to your **webpack.config.js**

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
        "TweenLite": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite.js'),
        "TweenMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js'),
        "TimelineLite": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js'),
        "TimelineMax": path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax.js'),
        "ScrollMagic": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js'),
        "animation.gsap": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js'),
        "debug.addIndicators": path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js')
    },
  },
```

And then use that in your js file:

```
import ScrollMagic from "scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic";
import "scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap";
import "scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators";
import TweenMax from "gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax";
import TimelineMax from "gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax";
```

More information you can find here ->
https://www.grzegorowski.com/scrollmagic-setup-for-webpack-commonjs

P.S. I did it and now it works.

**UPDATE:**
The solution above works with older version of GSAP.
For new version **3+** you can find nice information here -> https://greensock.com/forums/topic/20434-react-gsap-scrollmagic-animationgsap-not-found/

My imports with ScrollMagic 2.0.7 and GSAP 3.6.0 looks:

```
import ScrollMagic from "scrollmagic";
import "scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators";
import { gsap, Power1 } from "gsap";
import { TweenMax, TimelineMax } from "gsap";
import { ScrollMagicPluginGsap } from "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap";

ScrollMagicPluginGsap(ScrollMagic, gsap);
```

Don't forget to install **scrollmagic**, **gsap** and **scrollmagic-plugin-gsap**